# when call ipfs nft by api take too long time to load

Tags: nft, ipfs

For example, when I want to load the below NFT, it takes a very long time to load it.
How to load NFT very faster?

```
ipfs://QmTfFq8CY4M1ZHFm5UMZQQqtETyvaQNHnJiTTiNjHCyJSu
```

I load it by replacing **ipfs://** with **https://ipfs.io/ipfs/**:

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTfFq8CY4M1ZHFm5UMZQQqtETyvaQNHnJiTTiNjHCyJSu
```

Comment: This is not a Tezos issue. ipfs and https are not protocols that Tezos operates on. Smart contracts can use such metadata but these are implemented by the contract writers. Talk to your wallet maker for ipfs/https support issues.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not Tezos problem, but I think here is a good palace to ask my question related to web3.
If you know a better place to ask web3 questions, tell me, please! @utdrmac

Comment: @Taleb you can ask questions related to ipfs on the main stackoverflow site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your speed may vary because of many factors. As utdrmac said this is not a Tezos problem but usually related with IPFS. Take a look at https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/ for the fastest gateway for you and using it or trying out other gateways should help improve your speed.